# Deploying Azure Database by importing .bacpac

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

> The ImportExport operation with Request Id
> '3916c45d-e9e1-4ad0-9cab-684e6868ca0c' failed due to 'An error
> occurred while communicating with the SQL Server using
> AdPassword-login: <soapenv:Envelope
> xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soapenv:Body<soapenv:Fault
> xmlns:axis2ns5455168="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">axis2ns5455168:ClientThe
> service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR)
> /services/mex-ut1</soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'.
> (Code: ImportExportJobError)

I've been trying to create a database using a .bacpac file my professor gave me and I am not having any luck.. I keep getting this error.

Comment: Review xml if correct

Comment: Where you are creating database, could you please provide some more details regarding your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Verify

1. The username & password are correct
2. The same authentication type that was used when creating the database (Azure AD or SQL authentication)